# onProgressUpdate not called

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Why is `onProgressUpdate` not being called?

```
public class DoStuff extends AsyncTask<Integer, Integer, String> {
    private MainActivity activity;

    public DoStuff(MainActivity a){
        activity = a;
    }

    protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
        Integer loops = params[0];
        for (int i = 0; i <= loops.intValue() ; i++) {

            SystemClock.sleep(1000);
            publishProgress(new Integer((i / loops) * 100));

        }
        return "Done: " + loops.intValue();
    }

    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress)
    {
        activity.updateProgress("" + progress.intValue() + "%");
    }

}
```

Comment: protected String doInBackground(Integer... params) {
Log.d("TEST", "vals "+Arrays.asList(loops));
       Integer loops = params[0];

Comment: In addition to answers, use the `@Override` annotation to help prevent this type of mistake. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/94361/when-do-you-use-javas-override-annotation-and-why) for more details.

Comment: Use @Override .... Then compiler will inform you that you didn't override method... Or did it wrong...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using wrong signature for `onProgressUpdate`

Change

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress)
{
    activity.updateProgress(""+progress.intValue() +"%");
}
```

to

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress)
{
    activity.updateProgress(""+progress[0].intValue() +"%");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to change:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer progress) {
    activity.updateProgress(""+progress.intValue() +"%");
}
```

to:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
   activity.updateProgress(""+progress.intValue() +"%");
}
```

Parameters must be a varargs of the type that you declared as second